# Добавление Blur Effect в DataTrigger

Tags: wpf

Как добавить эффект размытия `BlurEffect` в `DataTrigger`?

Имеется такой стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShow}">
            <DataTrigger.Value>
                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
            </DataTrigger.Value>
            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger.Setters>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Visibility нужно заменить на размытие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
<DataTrigger.Setters>
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger.Setters>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, там в чате есть вопрос)))

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.